# Does not contain a definition for "Username" and no extension method "Username"

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

[It said that username does not contain a definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXF78.png)

see link for the error

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AspNetUsers.Email) <-- This don't through me error
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AspNetUsers.*Username*) <-- But this one yes, it said the usernam don't contain a definition.
```

I don't why its through me that, i have username in AspnetUsers. I'm working with relations with entity framework, all works good but when i want to show the username and not the email it said me that.

This is my model for AspNetUsers:

```
public string Id { get; set; }
public string Email { get; set; }
public bool EmailConfirmed { get; set; }
public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
public string SecurityStamp { get; set; }
public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
public bool PhoneNumberConfirmed { get; set; }
public bool TwoFactorEnabled { get; set; }
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

Comment: `item.AspNetUsers` looks like a collection, not a single entity object.

Comment: AspNetUser is the default table the Asp.Net create for login, my problem is that on the index of my table contenedores it shows me the email and i want to see the username in the controller a change to username and it show it but in the index no when i change it to Username it said me that.

Comment: Well, it's a simple question. What's the *exact* type of `item.AspNetUsers`?

Comment: C# is case sensitive, it's `UserName` in your model, but `Username` in your cshtml.

Comment: Yes, that was my error a fricking UpperCase Letter. Thanks Eris